# Selenium Webdrive (VBA) - find an element's attribute, where there are duplicate attributes of the same name

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to store the value "1234567!1234567" from the attribute `data-orderid` in a cell within my worksheet

The code I'm using in VBA is:

```
Cells(x,y) = d.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/table[3]/tr[@class='report']").getAttribute("data-orderid").Text
```

And this is an example of the HTML code I am trying to get the info from:

```
<body>
<table class="report">
    <tr class="wide">...</tr>
    <tr data-orderid="1234567!1234567" data-index="1" data- 
    thumbnail="www.image.jpg">...</tr>`
```

The expected output is "1234567!1234567" but the error: `NoSuchElementError, ElementNotFound` pops up as I try to run my code

Comment: Is your xpath correct?

Comment: Try this XPath `//*[contains(@data-orderid,'!')]  `

Comment: Can you share the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. The method for selenium vba is `Attribute`

```
d.findElementByCss("[data-index='1']").Attribute("data-orderid")
```

You don't need `.text` on the end.

Comment: Thank you! I was pulling my hair out over this one.
Just FYI the one without .text worked for me